# How to initiate TextView in tabView?

Tags: java, android, android-layout

**EDIT:** I have tried to find textView under bad View.

I have activity with tabView which contains two tabs. For each tab i want to have different layout. How can i initiate my element from each view? I´m trying to do that from my activity but when i´m searching for my element it returns null. Here is my code with only one tab.

My activity.

```
public class MyTariffListActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView tariffName;

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.tab_view_layout);

    tariffName = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tariffName);


    TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
    tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("Basic Info"));        

    tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL);

    final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    final PageAdapterTariff adapter = new PageAdapterTariff
            (getSupportFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

    Tariff tariff = getIntent().getParcelableExtra(MyCommonListActivity.TARIFF);

    tariffName.setText(tariff.getName()); // HERE tariffName is null

    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));

    tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
            // viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
        }

        @Override
        public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

        }
    });
} 
}
```

My pageAdapter

```
public class PageAdapterTariff extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
int mNumOfTabs;

public PageAdapterTariff(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
    super(fm);
    this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int position) {

    switch (position) {
        case 0:
            TariffInfoTab tariffInfoTab = new TariffInfoTab();
            return tariffInfoTab;
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return mNumOfTabs;
   }
}
```

My tab definition:

```
public class TariffInfoTab extends Fragment {



@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_my_show_tariff, container, false);

   }
}
```

My activity_my_show_tariff layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" tools:context=".MainActivity">

<TextView
            android:id="@+id/tariffName"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_span="3"
            android:padding="3dip" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

Refer this. It will help you.
[android-material-design-working-with-tabs](http://www.androidhive.info/2015/09/android-material-design-working-with-tabs/)